# unable to post json data , response message is SyntaxError: unexpected token <

Tags: php, jquery, json

also i did not get any console error and i check network tab i get 200 ok message that means data is posted..  please help

Here is jquery code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mc_subscribe').submit(function() {
        $('#response').html('form submitting....');
        var form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).prop('action'),
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: form.serialize()
        }).done(function(data){
            if (data.success == true){
                $('#mc_subscribe')[0].reset();
             $('#response').addClass('alert-success').removeClass('alert-danger').html(data.message);
             window.setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.href = data.redirectURL;
    }, 2000);
            } else{
             $('#response').addClass('alert-danger').removeClass('alert-success').html(data);
            }
            
        }).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, data ) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + data );
});;
        return false;
    });
});
```

Here is my codignitor controller code

```html
class Subscribe extends CI_Controller {

 private $data;

 public function index() {
     if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()){
         $result = $this->_subscribe();
         echo json_encode($result);
         exit;
     }
     
     $this->load->view('header');
     $this->load->view('pages/subscribe', $this->data);
     $this->load->view('footer');
 }

 private function _subscribe(){
     
     $success = true;
     $redirectURL = base_url() + '/pricing';

     if(!$this->input->post('FNAME')){
         $message =  "No Full Name provided";
         $success = false;
     }
     if( empty($this->input->post('EMAIL')) || !preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*$/i", $_POST['EMAIL']) ){
         $message =  "No Email address provided";
         $success = false;
     }
     if($success && !$this->input->post('MOBILE')){
         $message =  "No Phone Number provided";
         $success = false;
     }
     if($success && !$this->input->post('DAYTIME')){
         $message =  "No Day & Time provided";
         $success = false;
     }
     if ($success){
         
         $this->load->library('Mcapi', array(
             'apikey' => $this->config->item('mailchimp_key')
         ));
         
         $api = new Mcapi($this->config->item('mailchimp_key'));
   $list_id = $this->config->item('mailchimp_list_id');
   
   $merge_vars = Array( 
          'FNAME' => $this->input->post('FNAME'),
          'MOBILE' => $this->input->post('MOBILE'),
          'DAYTIME' => $this->input->post('DAYTIME')
      ); 
      
   if($api->listSubscribe($list_id, $_POST['EMAIL'], $merge_vars, '') === true) { 
             //  It worked!
             $message = 'Success!';
         } else {
             $success = false;
             //  An error ocurred, return error message
             $message =  'Error: ' . $api->errorMessage;
         }
     }
     return array('message' => $message, 'success' => $success, 'redirectURL' => $redirectURL);

 }

}
```

and here is  HTML form

```html
  <div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <form id="mc_subscribe" class="form-horizontal" action="http://localhost/CI-2/Subscribe/" method="post">
      <fieldset>

      <!-- Form Name -->
      <legend>SUBSCRIBE</legend>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for=""></label>  
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <input id="" name="FNAME" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" class="form-control input-md" required=""> 
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for=""></label>  
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <input id="" name="EMAIL" type="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control input-md" required="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for=""></label>  
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <input id="" name="MOBILE" type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" class="form-control input-md" required="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for=""></label>  
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <input id="" name="DAYTIME" type="text" placeholder="Day &amp; Time" class="form-control input-md" required="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for=""></label> 
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="SUBSCRIBE">
        </div>
      </div>

      </fieldset>
    </form>
    <p id="response" class="alert text-center" align="center"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Let us know if this code is on love server .

Comment: try calling console.log(data) before if loop in ajax.done function

see what u get in return.

Comment: The JSON is incorrect.

Comment: change return array('message' => $message, 'success' => $success, 'redirectURL' => $redirectURL);  to 

$data['message'] = $message ; 
$data['success'] = $succcess;
$data['redirectURL'] = $redirectURL;

return json_encode($data);

Comment: @Friyank i tried to output data and did not get anything .. even i hardcode json data

Comment: also response message is parseerror

Comment: convert the datatype to local from json , it seems ur code is not returning proper json

Comment: i changed datatype to text and output the data,   i get entire html page..  if datatype is json then .done function never execute

Comment: make it local @javid not text  ,some data type issue it is facing

Comment: sorry what you mean "make it local "  @Friyank

Comment: dataType: 'local', hope this work .. it works for me when i return some array or local variable values instead json

Comment: ahh, i get this response ,  No conversion from text to local

Comment: also  Response Headers is  Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8

Comment: The token-type you are passing in the **REQUEST-HEADER** might not be available on the SERVER-API or you might be passing the wrong token type in the HEADER

Comment: 100% sure, the problem is within the HEADER of the REQUEST

Answer (score 0):

change this below line

```
return array('message' => $message, 'success' => $success, 'redirectURL' => $redirectURL);
```

TO

```
$data = array();

$data['message'] = $message ; 
$data['success'] = $succcess; 
$data['redirectURL'] = $redirectURL; 

return json_encode($data);
```

in your controller.

it seems you are not returning the data in the json format,